# How to create multiple instance of C# window service in runtime(dynamically) from window application

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created a window service and controlling start and stop from another window application. All this are working fine.My window service is reading text files and inserting the values into database .And text file location is taking from window application.The problem is if customer want to give multiple location what i have to do?
so i thought if i can create multiple instance of my window service from that window application my problem will be solved .
So, my question is how can i create multiple instance of window service? is it possible? have anyone tried it before?

Comment: It is not possible. Only one instance of a service can be run at a time. You can handle multiple location in same service.

Comment: Write a thread for that method. For each new location, create a new thread.

Comment: In my window service timer will call the method in every 10 seconds. And text file will be coming in every second so if i will add a loop to read multiple location it may hang  in some cases like if i have more than 1000 file in a folder.

Comment: That's why I am suggesting you to create thread.

Comment: Disagree with using threads. You should be able to do this single thread and just using `FileWatcher` and a callback